# Spring Azure AD SSO - AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: spring, spring-security

Experts,

In my spring boot 2.5.5 app, I have the following dependencies for SSO with Azure AD.

Reference: https://github.com/pateluday07/saml-sso-and-slo-demo-idp-azure-sp-springboot

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties has the below entries

```
service.provider.entity.id=APPNAME
idp.metedata.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<ID>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=<AppID>
saml.keystore.password= password
saml.private.key.alias= alias
saml.private.key.password: password
saml.keystore.file=classpath:/saml/dev/samlKeystore.jks
```

On the Azure Side, an app is created with Entity Id as APPNAME and Reply URL as https://servername/appname/saml/SSO

Now when the app is deployed on the server - servername and accessed I get the following error

[image]

Strangely if I change the reply URL on Azure to http://localhost:8080/appname/saml/SSO and deploy the app locally and access it, then it works.

Any idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I know I saw this only 2 months later, but I think the problem you are having is the same one as one I often have.

I am replying anyway in case you have yet to find a solution and to help others with similar problems.

Who knows, maybe someone at Microsoft will see this and fix the error message so that it displays the "request" URL that we must match in Azure.

- The Spring Azure libraries choose the reply URL for you.  I do not know the exact one for SAML, but if you use Oauth2 it is something like "https://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/".
- The reply URL chosen by the Spring Azure libraries is different if you use an embedded app server (i.e.: Tomcat) or if you deploy as a WAR to an instance of the server.  For example, the above URL changed to https://localhost/myWarApp/login/oauth2/code/ when I deployed to a Tomcat server on localhost that responds to port 80.
- If you deploy to a server other than localhost, you of course need to use the hostname.  In my case it was https://myHost.mydomain/myWarApp/login/oauth2/code/
- A lot of the documentation and tutorials you find googling are inaccurate.  In the example above I when I googled I got reply URLs that did not have the ending / and one that said it should end in /azure.
- The reply URL that the libraries use needs to be registered in Azure and match *exactly* or you will get the error that is bugging you.
- In Azure you record the reply URL under your Registered App / Authentication / Redirect URIs.  I have not tested it fully, but I think you can list the Redirect URIs for your various environments, so that the app will work in all of them.

Ultimately, it was frustration that drove me to Fiddler and a lot of digging to find the actual reply URL that was being sent by the libraries in the request to Azure (the one that doesn't match).